# Mock object to mock callback function

Tags: c++, c, googletest

I'm testing C source code using Google Test framework (gmock + gtest).

I need to test functions like:

```
Some_Comm_Bus_Function(int tx_buff*, int tx_size, int rx_buff*, int rx_size, CommIf_Callback_T callback_fun_ptr);
```

Where callback_fun_ptr is pointer to function of CommIf_Callback_T type.
Only way of mocking callback function, I can think of is manualy creating static method inside Some_Bus_Mock Class and the other methods to altering its return value, return-by-pointer values, call counter etc.
Basically the same mechanisms that gmock has.

Is there any way to create gmock with method that would be able to mock this callback function?

Not sure if this callback should be called mock or fake. What I want to achieve is I want to create callback that would have easy way of changing behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think `MockFunction` might be the tool tha's just right for you, please see [the documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#useful-mocks-created-using-gmock).